# Measure inequality of open interval

Tags: real-analysis

show that if 0 < r < 1 and E is a measurable set with 0 < m(E) < ∞ , then there exist an open interval I such that m(I ∩ E) > rl(I) ,  where m is measure and l(I) is length of I

Comment: At what point in your course are you asking this question from? This statement has multiple proofs, so which answer works for you depends on whether you've seen the Lebesgue differentiation theorem. If you haven't, a very weak hint: argue by contradiction, and try to get to $m(E)<m(E)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix one such $r$ and suppose there is no such interval; this means any interval will satisfy $m(I∩ E) \leq r|I|$. To exploit this, for any epsilon, take a cover of $E$ by open intervals $\{I_k\}_{k=1}^∞ $ such that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{∞} \left|I_k\right| \leq   m(E) + \varepsilon
\end{align*}
which is possible as $m(E)$ is defined as an infimum of such covers. Then as they form a cover, we have

\begin{align*}
m(E) = m\left(E∩ \bigcup_k I_k \right) = m\left(\bigcup_k E∩ I_k \right)  \overset{\tiny \text{subadd.}}{\leq} \sum m(E∩ I_k) \leq r\sum \left|I_k\right| 
 \leq r\left[m(E) + \varepsilon \right] 
\end{align*}
and thus $m(E) \leq r m(E) + \varepsilon_0 $ for any $\varepsilon_0 > 0$; but this can't be true (try $\varepsilon_0 = \frac{1-r}{2} m(E) > 0$.)

Answer (score 1):

By Lebesgue's density theorem, for almost every $x \in E$, we have that $\displaystyle \frac{ m(E \cap (x - \delta, x + \delta))}{2\delta} \to 1$ as $\delta \to 0$.  In particular, since $m(E) > 0$, the set of points of $E$ with full density is not empty.  So find an $x$ where this happens.   Thus if $0 < r < 1$, for all sufficiently small $\delta$, $\displaystyle \frac{m(E \cap (x - \delta, x + \delta))}{2 \delta}  > r$.  Taking $I = (x - \delta, x + \delta)$ and rearranging that last inequality, we're done.